# Best way extract mention from text with link like wikipedia dump

Tags: python-3.x

I got data from Wikipedia dump like below:

```
' The atomic number or proton number (symbol Z) of a <a href="chemical%20element">chemical element</a> is the number of <a href="proton">proton</a>s found in the <a href="atomic%20nucleus">nucleus</a> of an <a href="atom">atom</a>.'  
' It is identical to the <a href="charge%20number">charge number</a> of the nucleus.',  
' The atomic number uniquely identifies a chemical element.'  
' In an <a href="electric%20charge">uncharged</a> atom, the atomic number is also equal to the number of <a href="electron">electron</a>s.'
```

I want to extract the mention(text spans with hyperlink followed up) from these sentences. The expected outputs are:

```
["chemical element", "proton", "nucleus", "atom"]  
["charge number"],  
[] 
["uncharged", "electron"]
```

I wonder what would be the best way to extract such kind of information from the text. Thanks.

Comment: also share the link of the Wikipedia page

Comment: @YashMakan here is the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=673 for this example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to extract text from between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181631/efficient-way-to-extract-text-from-between-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are handling HTML, you can try using the Beautiful Soup library for the dump.
The exact code will look something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Enter the line from dump here

soup = BeautifulSoup(your_string, "html.parser")

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags from the parsed information
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print('Contents:{}\n'.format(tag.contents[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to capture those values using `re.findall`:

```py
import re

vals = [
    ' The atomic number or proton number (symbol Z) of a <a href="chemical%20element">chemical element</a> is the number of <a href="proton">proton</a>s found in the <a href="atomic%20nucleus">nucleus</a> of an <a href="atom">atom</a>.',
' It is identical to the <a href="charge%20number">charge number</a> of the nucleus.',  
' The atomic number uniquely identifies a chemical element.',
' In an <a href="electric%20charge">uncharged</a> atom, the atomic number is also equal to the number of <a href="electron">electron</a>s.',
]


for val in vals:
    matches = re.findall('<a[^>]*>([\w\s]+)<\/a>', val)
    print(matches)
```

See the pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/ntgiT9/2)