# how to get href link by text in Python

Tags: python

This is part of the web html content:

```
<a href="https://www.cnbeta.com/articles/science/1062069.htm"><strong>阅读全文</strong></a>
```

how to get the href of the a by using `阅读全文` content? I just want to get this href from the whole web page and exclude other href. Now I am using bs4 to parse, and stucking in get the href url:

```
def parse_content(self, original_content, link):
        http_domain = urlparse(link)
        website_name = http_domain.netloc
        if website_name.__contains__("cnbeta.com"):
            print("start get url from original content" )
```

Comment: Do you have any code? How are you parsing the HTML?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to extract text from between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181631/efficient-way-to-extract-text-from-between-tags)

Comment: no，it may find all tag with a , i just want to find one@Tomerikoo

Comment: The simplest approach could be to loop over _all_ `<a>` tags and stop once you find the tag that has this text inside.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007653/how-to-find-tag-with-particular-text-with-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try `BeautifulSoup`.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample_html = """
<a href="https://www.cnbeta.com/articles/science/1062069.htm"><strong>阅读全文</strong></a>
<a href="https://www.cnbeta.com/articles/science/1062068.htm"><strong>RANDOM TEXT!</strong></a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample_html, "html.parser").find_all(lambda t: t.name == "a" and t.text.startswith("阅"))

print([a["href"] for a in soup])
```

Output:

```
['https://www.cnbeta.com/articles/science/1062069.htm']
```